# How can I retrieve specific data from Core Data in this case?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am trying to retrieve the coordinates based on a specific mapname (in this case "farm") but somehow I can't get it to work.

My entities are "Map" and "Coordinates" with attributes "name", "latitude" and "longitude" respectively. Where have I made a mistake or what should I do differently to be able to access coordinates specific to only one mapname?

```
fileprivate var fetchedResultsControllerForCoordinateEntity: NSFetchedResultsController<Coordinate> = {
// Create Fetch Request
let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Coordinate> = Coordinate.fetchRequest()

fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "latitude", ascending: true)]
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "longitude", ascending: true)]

// Create Fetched Results Controller
let fetchedResultsControllerForCoordinateEntity = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

return fetchedResultsControllerForCoordinateEntity
}()


fileprivate var fetchedResultsControllerForMapEntity: NSFetchedResultsController<Map> = {
// Create Fetch Request
let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Map> = Map.fetchRequest()

// Configure Fetch Request
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)]
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format:"name == %@", "farm")

// Create Fetched Results Controller
let fetchedResultsControllerForMapEntity = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

return fetchedResultsControllerForMapEntity
}()




   var newMap = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Map", into: managedObjectContext)
    newMap.setValue(mapName, forKey: "name")


    for member in self.markersArray {
        var theCoordinate = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Coordinate", into: managedObjectContext)
        theCoordinate.setValue(member.latitude, forKey: "latitude")
        theCoordinate.setValue(member.longitude, forKey: "longitude")
        theCoordinate.setValue(newMap, forKey: "newRelationship")
  //newRelationship is a one-to-many relationship, as each map has several coordinates
    }
```

Comment: Are you calling managedObjectContext.save() after inserting the new objects?

Comment: Yes I do call that

Comment: Where is the code you are trying to retrieve? I don't see it. I see that you have a variable `fetchedResultsControllerForMapEntity` but I don't see you using it anywhere.